# mqtt - mosquito server log shows "Error in poll: Interrupted system call." when receiving a SIGHUP

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

could anyone tell me whether I should be worried about this error:
"Error in poll: Interrupted system call."

in the mqtt broker mosquito log when sending it a SIGHUP signal to reload its config file ? (in order to take in account a new user/password being created when mosquito runs)

Can I assume that mosquito only reloads its configuration & nothing happen to the established connections & messages under reception or/and publication from various clients when this takes place ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't help with the error, but if you are making lots of changes to the ACL/username and password list can I suggest you use jpmens' plugin to store that in a DB so you don't have to keep kicking the broker this way. https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error in poll` here is a non-error, it's just saying that your SIGHUP happened to occur when the code was in the call to poll() and that is the reason why poll() returned, rather than clients needing servicing. This message should be masked in version 1.4.14.

Comment: Thx a lot ralight for your answer